# Changing model value on input is changing the select options in vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

Select the First option **Fpo**, on select of the first item, i assigned first object in the list to **test** variable. I used **test.name** as a model to that input field. When i am trying to modify the input field, the select option is also changing. How it is working like that? In angular i did not see this problem. Is there any way that on change of the input field should not reflect on the select box option?

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    items: [{name: 'Fpo', value:'foo'},{name:'bar', value:'bar'}],
    test: {}
  }),
  methods: {
    assingValue: function () {
      this.test = this.items[0]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container fluid grid-list-xl>
      <v-layout wrap align-center>
        <v-flex xs12 sm6 d-flex>
          <v-select
            :items="items"
            label="Standard"
                    item-text="name"
                    item-value="value"
                    @change="assingValue"
          ></v-select>
        </v-flex>
        <v-flex>
                    <v-text-field v-model="test.name">
            </v-text-field>
          </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a deep clone (completely independent clone) of your object. So instead of this ..

`this.test = this.items[0];`

Do this ..

`this.test = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.items[0]));`

[See the modified pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qJWaLE?editors=1011)

Answer (score 1):

That's related to Vue reactivity. take a look at https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

> Sometimes you may want to assign a number of properties to an existing
> object, for example using Object.assign() or _.extend(). However, new
> properties added to the object will not trigger changes. In such
> cases, create a fresh object with properties from both the original
> object and the mixin object:
>
> ```
> // instead of `Object.assign(this.someObject, { a: 1, b: 2 })`
> this.someObject = Object.assign({}, this.someObject, { a: 1, b: 2 })
> ```

Basically if you set those like you did using the equal sign, instead of copying the value it just starts pointing to the same place, so if you change any of them they will both change..

You can change your code to:

```
assingValue: function () {
  this.test = Object.assign({name: this.items[0].name})
}
```

check this [link of the modified codepen](https://codepen.io/edunicastro/pen/dgbprM?editors=1010)

Comment: Its a deep copy, is it possible to copy the whole object to this.test ?